# SQL query to get rows contains value of another query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables `transaction` and query. `Transaction` table have unique `tid` and the `query` table has `tid_(subtransactionid)`.

I want to get the list of all `subtransactions by using tid`.

I tried this

```
select *
from queries, transactions
where queries.id like 'transactions.tid%' and transactions.uid = 'NfPgWM1igYh2y2hDKrLWLOxyI6u1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the tables and use the operator `LIKE` in the `ON` clause:

```
select q.* 
from queries q inner join transactions t
on q.tid like concat(t.tid, '%') 
where t.uid = 'NfPgWM1igYh2y2hDKrLWLOxyI6u1'
```

If your database does not support the function `concat()` then you can use either:

```
on q.tid like t.tid || '%'
```

or:

```
on q.tid like t.tid + '%'
```

Comment: Can I limit t.tid? I want results for 15 transactions only.

Comment: What is your database? Mysql, SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: Then use `select top 15 q.*....` but it would be better to ad an ORDER BY clause at the end, because if you don't then the 15 rows that you get will be arbitrary.

Comment: thanks for the reply but select top 15 ... throwing error

Comment: Are you sure that you are using SQL Server?